# Why do I have each character written separately, in each cell of the Excel workbook

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a code that automatically reads information in a specific Excel cell, across all sheets. Next, I want this data to be filled in with a column in a separate Excel table.
The data is written, but each character of the data from the previously read table is filled in a separate cell.

Here is a piece of code that is responsible for this.

```
def xlsx2():
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active

    ws['A1'] = 'Монтажник(и)'
    ws['B1'] = 'Номер шкафа'
    ws['C1'] = 'Сумма'

    data = [
        list(f'{a1}, {b1}, {c1}')
    ]
    print(type(data))

    for row in data:
        ws.append(row)


    wb.save('example.xlsx')

def lists():

    filetypes = (
        ('Excel', '*.xlsx'),
        ('All files', '*.*'),
    )
    global filename6
    filename6 = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(
        title='Выбери таблицу',
        filetypes=filetypes,
    )

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(f'{filename6}', read_only=True, data_only = True)
    for sheet in wb:
        a1=sheet['A14'].value
        b1=sheet['B1'].value
        c1=sheet['D14'].value
        xlsx2()
```

The result is `example.xlsx` in the photo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ie0cP.png)

Comment: `list(f'{a1}, {b1}, {c1}')` You're calling `list()` on a string, which makes **each character** of the string into a separate list item.  I'm guessing maybe you meant `[a1, b1, c1]` instead?

Comment: TypeError: Value must be a list, tuple, range or generator, or a dict. Supplied value is <class 'NoneType'>.  


And if without `list()`, it outputs the following.
Value must be a list, tuple, range or generator, or a dict. Supplied value is <class 'str'>

Comment: This error message is meaningless by itself.  We need to see the **exact** code you changed.

Comment: @JohnGordon
I just deleted `list()`

Comment: Your minimal working code sample does not run. Those variables `{a1}, {b1}, {c1}` are not defined. Presumably they come from the `lists()` function but when the function `xlsx2()` is called these variables are not passed.

Comment: The line `f'{a1}, {b1}, {c1}'` would basically create a string from the three variables e.g. "word1, word2, word3". The string is converted into a list by wrapping in `list()`. The string is an iterable and so `list()` creates a list consisting of the iterable's items, thus (sticking with the values used previously); `list(f'{a1}, {b1}, {c1}')` would result in the list `['w', 'o', 'r', 'd', '1', ',', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd', '2', ',', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd', '3']`. Openpyxl append then writes each list element across the next unused Excel row, with each element assigned to the next free cell.

Answer (score 0):

The variables a1, b1 and c1 are specific to the function 'lists()' so are unknown in the function 'xlsx2()'
For your code to work you want to pass the variables to xlsx2 and then just add them to a list.

```
...
def xlsx2(a1, b1, c1):  # Variables from lists()
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active

    ws['A1'] = 'Монтажник(и)'
    ws['B1'] = 'Номер шкафа'
    ws['C1'] = 'Сумма'

    # data = [
    #     list(f'{a1}, {b1}, {c1}')
    # ]

    data = [a1, b1, c1]  # Add to a list for appending
    print(type(data))

    # for row in data:
    ws.append(data)

    wb.save('example.xlsx')


def lists():
    filetypes = (
        ('Excel', '*.xlsx'),
        ('All files', '*.*'),
    )

    filename6 = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(
        title='Выбери таблицу',
        filetypes=filetypes,
    )

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(f'{filename6}', read_only=True, data_only=True)
    for sheet in wb:
        a1 = sheet['A14'].value
        b1 = sheet['B1'].value
        c1 = sheet['D14'].value
        xlsx2(a1, b1, c1)  # call xlsx2 with values for a1, b1 & c1 


lists()
```